# Compactness Argument

Tags: general-topology

Consider the inclusion chain of real valued intervals

$\displaystyle \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \left( a(k),b_\varepsilon(k)\right)\supset \bigcup_{k=1}^\infty (a(k),b(k)]\supset (a,b]\supset [a_\varepsilon,b]$

where $b_\varepsilon(k) > b(k)$ and $a_\varepsilon\in (a,b)$

What is drawn as conclusion is that there exists a $K_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that

$\displaystyle \bigcup_{k=1}^{K_0} \left( a(k),b_\varepsilon(k) \right)\supset (a_\varepsilon,b]$

This is called a compactness argument in the book I am reading and is used to reduce an infinite sum to a finite one for an open cover of a set.

However, I do not understand this argument. Why is it that we can find such a $K_0$? From what I understand, the argument relies on the fact, that there cannot be a cover which covers both ends of the interval $(a_\varepsilon, b]$ if one end is not covered with a finite sum. But why is this?

Comment: Are $a(k)$ and $b(k)$ increasing and decreasing sequences, respectively?

Comment: For the first inclusion you been $b_{\epsilon} (k) >b(k)$ not $b_{\epsilon} (k) <b(k)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Made an edit, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $[a_\varepsilon,b]$ is compact and since $\left\{\bigl(a(k),b_\varepsilon(k)\bigr)\,\middle|\,k\in\mathbb N\right\}$ is an open cover of $[a_\varepsilon,b]$, it has a finite subcover $\left\{\bigl(a(k_1),b_\varepsilon(k_1)\bigr),\bigl(a(k_2),b_\varepsilon(k_2)\bigr),\ldots,\bigl(a(k_n),b_\varepsilon(k_n)\bigr)\right\}$. Take $K_0=\max\{k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n\}$. Then$$[a_\varepsilon,b]\subset\bigcup_{k=1}^{K_0}\bigl(a(k),b_\varepsilon(k)\bigr).$$

Answer (score 1):

Actually $[a_{\epsilon},b] \subset \cup_{k=1}^{K_0} (a(k),b_{\epsilon} (k))$ for some $K_0$. We  can include both end points. This follows by compactness of the closed interval $[a_{\epsilon},b] $.